# Use long press gesture with AVFoundation to start stop recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, long-press

Hi I would like to start stop a recording with AVFoundation coding in Objective-C with long press gesture.

I know how to start a recording and stop it with another button, but not doing it all with the same one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code in github very little and posted the code below. The reason i added the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` is because otherwise your `PLAYBUTTON`s clicks are ignored because of the long press gesture. And i changed `[gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:0];` to 0 seconds for avoiding a delay.

When I run the project it works perfectly as you have asked:)
Here is the .h

```
//viewcontroller.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
- (void)longPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress;
- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here is the implementation:

```
//viewcontroller.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    gesture1.delegate = self;
    [gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:0];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];


    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)longPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress {
    if(([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) || ([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
        NSLog(@"long press ended");
        [recorder stop];
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
    }
    else if([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"long press detected");

        if (player.playing) {
            [player stop];
        }

        if (!recorder.recording) {
            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [session setActive:YES error:nil];

            // Start recording
            [recorder record];
        }
    }
}


- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"playTapped");
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

#pragma mark - AVAudioRecorderDelegate

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording");
    [playButton setEnabled:YES];
}

#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done"
                                                    message: @"Finish playing the recording!"
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    // test if our control subview is on-screen
    if (playButton.superview != nil) {
        if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:playButton]) {
            // we touched our control surface
            return NO; // ignore the touch
        }
    }
    return YES; // handle the touch
}


@end
```

Comment: I'm now trying to concentrate the long press on a new "record" button, I'll keep you updated on how the app advance!

Comment: Ok I added a button in storyboard, I added a property recordButton in .h, I linked property with the button. Added recordButton to synthesize in .m. In the long press implementation I changed longPress and used sender like for the button play, and I added this line recordButton = (UIButton*)sender.view; The button works, but the long press also works outside the button :( should I use a Container View?

Comment: I also changed/add those lines in viewDidLoad 
[recordButton addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
    [self.view addSubview:recordButton];

Comment: nice:) if there is any more trouble i will try to help. take care i am going to sleep now:D

Comment: and how did you do it?

Comment: I looked around on the web and stuff!

Thanks good night my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` simply like this inside

`- (void) viewDidLoad {....}`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
//[gesture1 setDelegate:self]; you won't need this most probably if detecting the long press is your only expectation from the gesture recognizer
[gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
//instead of [self addGest... you can try [self.view addGest.. as follows:
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
```

and when the user presses the view for at least 1 seconds this function is fired:

```
-(void)longPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress {
    if(([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) || ([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
        NSLog(@"long press ended");
        //[self stopRecording];
    }
    else if([longPress state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"long press detected");
        //[self startRecording];
    }
}
```

instead of the old way you were using with the UIButton:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button press detected");
    //[self startRecording];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure, will it stop the recording when I stop pressing the button? I'm new to this kind of developement

Comment: You are perfectly right. i made a small modification in the longPressed method. can you please try it and give feedback? This way when the user starts a longpress for 1 sec, the recording starts and when the user takes the finger away or when a phonecall comes the recording stops

Comment: If this works and you dont want the 1 second delay before the start recording, i will change the answer to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in conjuction with the current solution

Comment: By the way you said "when I stop pressing the button". Are you adding the gesture recognizer to a button? With my solution, you dont need to touch the button. you can long press on anywhere in the screen. Note: presenting some code would help us

Comment: Is there a way to share code outside the comment box, because it is too long?

Comment: :) first try to adopt my solution. if you don't have any luck we can try to upload the code. You can upload the whole project to gitHub. Having an account on gitHub is a must being a software guy anyways:D

Comment: Ok cool! I have an account on github! I'll comment here when I finished what you advice me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok I think I got it, my first version was working with 3 buttons, record, stop, play, I thought it was a lot of button for nothing. I kept the play button to play the recorded memo. And I added the long press. However I don't know how to link the long press with a record button. I think it was correctly pushed here https://github.com/ilanoh/memovocal2

Comment: It's the first time I use xcode, I think that I need a course about this actually, it's more complex that it looks :(